# connecting geth to web3.go 1.0 via websockets or HTTP

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, ethereumjs, golang

Is there anyThing similar to web3.js written in go that allows me to communicate with the geth client ?

Answer (score 0):

The web3.js equivalent for Go is geth ([go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum)) itself:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "math/big"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)

func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://mainnet.infura.io")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    account := common.HexToAddress("0x71c7656ec7ab88b098defb751b7401b5f6d8976f")
    balance, err := client.BalanceAt(context.Background(), account, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(balance) // 13468896094452636291

    f := new(big.Float)
    f.SetString(balance.String())
    ethValue := new(big.Float).Quo(f, big.NewFloat(math.Pow10(18)))
    fmt.Println(ethValue) // 13.468896094452636291
}
```

For more examples, visit the [Ethereum Development with Go](https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-development-with-go-book) guide book.